# AWS CLI - List Unencrypted Volumes and Filter Results --query

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to use AWS CLI to list all unencrypted volumes and the associated tag key value for the tag key 'application'. I'm having difficulty getting the -query portion correct for the desired filtering. If I run:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=encrypted,Values=false Name=tag-key,Values=application
```

I get all of the volume information, which I do not want. If I add in the --query as shown below I only get the tag key values. I want the VolumeId as well but I'm unable to get the syntax for the correct after multiple attempts.

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=encrypted,Values=false Name=tag-key,Values=application --query 'Volumes[].[ [Tags[?Key==`application`].Value][0][0],[Tags[?Key==`tag_component_name`].Value][0][0] ]'
```

Again, I simply want to output VolumeID and tag key values for the tag key 'application' for all unencrypted volumes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--filters` to limit *which* resources are returned and use `--query` to specify what data you would like displayed.

This will list only unencrypted volumes and will display the `VolumeId` and the value of the `application` tag:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=encrypted,Values=false --query 'Volumes[].[VolumeId,Tags[?Key==`application`]|[0].Value]' --output text
```

Depending upon your operating system, you might need to play with the quotation marks.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for your help.